# Convert response body from XML to Json in API Management Policy Expression when forwarding response to different URL

Tags: c#, html, xml, razor, azure-api-management

How can I change the response body from XML to Json when forwarding the response to a different URL?

I'm specifically forwarding the response to Azure Service Bus.

I've tried many different ways to serialize XML to json but with no luck because of the restrictions of some JsonConvert methods that's not allowed in policy expressions.

And no, `<json-to-xml apply="content-type-json" consider-accept-header="true" />` is not the solution :)

```
<outbound>
    <base />
        <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="response_body" timeout="60" ignore-error="true">
            <set-url>https://servicebus.fake</set-url>
            <set-method>POST</set-method>
            <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
                <value>@{

                  // some code to construct the token key that's needed for service bus requests.

                  }
                </value>
            <set-header name="MessageId" exists-action="skip">
                <value>@{
                  var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                  return guid;
                  }
                </value>
            </set-header>
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
                <set-body>@{

                        // What must I add here?
                }
                </set-body>
       </send-request>
       <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>application/json</value>
        </set-header>
    </outbound>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution :) The typical JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode method isn't allowed in policy expressions.

However good ol' `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` did the trick.

```
<send-one-way-request mode="new">
    <set-url>http://requestb.in/xje199xj</set-url>
    <set-method>POST</set-method>
    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
        <value>application/json</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-body>@{
            string xml = context.Response.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc);
        }
    </set-body>
</send-one-way-request>
```